# Element with name or id usable by default

Tags: javascript, html

I came along some code today of which I was pretty sure it wouldn't work. Turned out I was wrong. This works for both IE and Chrome.

```
<img onmouseover="why(this)" src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="" />
<img onmouseover="why(this)" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
<br>
<img id="preview" src="" alt="" />
<img name="preview2" src="" alt="" />
```

```
function why(obj) {
    preview.src = obj.src;
    preview2.src = obj.src;
}
```

Why does this work? Aren't we supposed to use `document.getElementById`?
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/MJfy8/)**

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/772035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because by default, all elements that have `id`s are dumped on the `window` object, using their `id` as their property name. Some browsers do the same with `name`. Since the `window` object is the global object in browsers, those seemingly-free-standing variables are resolved as properties of `window`.

It's not a good thing to rely on, because the global namespace is very crowded and it's really easy to shadow those. For instance:

```
function preview() { }
```

Now that element with the `id` `preview` isn't available as a global symbol anymore, because I've shadowed it with a function. Or

```
var preview;
```

Boom, it's gone.

Hence using `document.getElementById` and such when you're looking up elements.

---

Re your comments below:

> When I inspect the window object I can't find the property preview. Once I place a breakpoint in the function why however, window.preview suddenly is defined. Any idea how that works?
>
> I just added `window.preview` as a watch expression, it returns `undefined` untill I hit the brekpoint.

I would expect the properties to get created as those elements were parsed. So it would depend on when you stopped and looked at `window`: If you were looking at it before the parser reached those DOM elements, those properties would be `undefined`. And that's what I see with this page:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ScratchPad</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
debugger;
</script>
<div id="testelement"></div>
<script>
debugger;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As of the first `debugger;` statement, a watch (also using Chrome's devtools) on `window.testelement` shows `undefined`, but as of the second `debugger;` statement, it shows the div element.

Comment: When I inspect the window object I can't find the property `preview`. Once I place a breakpoint in the function `why` however, `window.preview` suddenly is defined. Any idea how that works?

Comment: @Jonathan: How are you inspecting the window object? These properties are only available in the JavaScript layer, not (say) in the DOM layer...

Comment: I just added `window.preview` as a watch expression, it returns `undefined` untill I hit the brekpoint. (Tested with Chrome devtools)

Comment: @Jonathan: I've added an update at the end of the answer.

Comment: Darn, I think I was just looking at jsFiddle's `window` object and `window` just switched to the `iframe` jsFiddle uses when it hit the breakpoint...